# Moving Sphere, Line Intersection?

Tags: geometry

Basically have a sphere with radius, position and a velocity. Which I need to find the intersection with a line that has a starting and end vertex.

Was thinking this could also be converted to a line-capsule/cylinder intersection?

Comment: Using a motion equation s = v*t + s0, where s0 = initial position, v = velocity, t = time, s = final position, you can evaluate the position of the sphere at any given amount of time. Along with the sphere equation (x - x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2 + (z-z0)^2 = r^2, you can use this to solve for sphere intersections with a line segment (assuming that a line segment is "a line that has a starting and end vertex").

Comment: How would you solve for t in that equation other than iterating through it...

Comment: Sorry, t is not time, but is instead the change in time (delta time). If you know the time interval (that is, when it starts and stops), you can calculate the time difference and plug that into the motion equation to find where the sphere is.

Comment: I need to calculate the exact answer without looping through it.

Comment: What are you trying to solve for? Are you trying to solve exactly when the sphere finally intersects with the line segment after some amount of time?

Comment: Well velocity is the total distance the sphere is going to travel. But yes I am trying to find the exact time, from 0.0 to 1.0. With 0.0 being the position and 1.0 translated by velocity.

Comment: I'm now confused. Velocity is the change in displacement over change in time (dv/dt). Displacement is the change of position relative to an arbitrary origin point.  When you say the initial position/displacement is at 0.0, do you mean the sphere starts centered at the origin (x = 0, y = 0, z = 0)? I don't understand the 1.0 figure (I assume this is a follow-up on how you defined velocity). The motion equation I gave you only works when the velocity stays constant.

Comment: It's a percentage, I only want to check if there is an intersection  along the current velocity. 0 means the sphere didn't move, 1.0 means it moved the total allowed distance.

Comment: So in mathematical terms: s0 = 0, s = k * maxs, where k is the percent, and maxs = maximum allowed displacement.

For the sphere intersection, do you want intersection for only the surface of the sphere, or do you want solid sphere intersection? Also, you may want to review parametric equations.

Comment: Cross reference: related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/23334141